# Setting writeObject in an infinite loop, to send data into a server

Tags: java

I'm creating a software, where multiple clients can draw on the "same" canvas. This is done by sending an ArrayList of drawn points to the server and back. As it is now, I've set up my ListArray, but I need it to update constantly, so the server always have the newest info.

Client code:

```
public class TCPClient extends JPanel {

    public static ArrayList<Point> location = new ArrayList<>();

    private JTextArea consoleOutput = new JTextArea(1,20);

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
        consoleOutput.setEditable(false);
    }

    public TCPClient() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                location.add(e.getPoint());
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                location.add(e.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }
        });
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(location.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

         Point p = location.get(0);
         for (int i = 1; i < location.size(); i++) {
             Point q = location.get(i);
             g.drawLine(p.x, p.y, q.x, q.y);
             p = q;
         }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[])  throws Exception {

        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
        ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        InetAddress SERVERIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing with friends");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new CanvasFrame(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JTextArea IPadress = new JTextArea(1,20);
        IPadress.setEditable(false);
        IPadress.append("DEVICE IP: " + SERVERIP.getHostAddress());
        frame.add(IPadress, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        outToServer.writeObject(location);

        clientSocket.close();

    }
}
```

As you can see, everything client/server related is in my main thread. I tried putting my writeObject method into a while loop inside the main thread, but it caused no results. 
Afterwards I tried making a new run() function, but that also seemed to mess up my in- and output streams.

Clarification: I need outToServer.writeObject(location); to be send repeatidly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell what you're talking about, but if you keep sending the same object you need to use `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()` or `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` to ensure fresh values are sent, or, more simply, create a new object each time instead of resending the same one.